# Magento customer password reset email

Tags: magento, passwords, reset

My situation:
I have 3 websites that named:
websiteA
websiteB
websiteC
all in one Magento installation. Customer data is shared in a global view. When a customer (registered on websiteA) requests a password reset on websiteB, they will receive a password reset email that directs them to websiteA to reset the password. I don't want that. I want the customer to receive a password reset email that directs them to websiteB.

Code I found in password reset email:

```
<a href="{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}">{{store url="customer/account/resetpassword/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}</a>
```

How can I modify this code to not use {{store url=}}, but still catch customer id and token information?

Comment: You could try creating a separate Transactional Email template for each website, then assigning that email template to each store configuration for the `Forgot Email Template` in `System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Password Options`.  I'm not sure if that will work though.  It seems odd Magento would even send an email if the customer isn't a member of the specific website they send it from.

Comment: I already tried that, but the password reset link will still be the one that customer registered originally.

Comment: Not if you insert the store url manually into each email template.

Comment: Thx Axel, I tried to insert store url instead of {{store url=}}, but I can't find a way to insert "_query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token" part.

Comment: Try something like: `http://yoursite.com/customer/account/resetpassword/?id={{var customer.id}}&token={{var customer.rp_token}}`

Comment: @Aexl I tried `<a href="http://www.websiteA.com/customer/account/resetpassword/?id={{var customer.id}}&token={{var customer.rp_token}}">link</a>`. I still received email with websiteB.com reset password link....

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to override the way Magento handles password reset emails.  It looks like the model is programmed to send the email template assigned to the website the customer is created from (not the website they are on).

Comment: Also, what are the chances of a customer doing a password reset on a website they never signed up for.  Unlikely, but I see where receiving an email from a different site could be confusing.  You can modify the model to check against the customer against the current website, and they don't exist...don't send the email.

Comment: I guess there is no easy solution for this problem. sigh... Thanks anyway @Axel

Comment: There never is with Magento, unfortunately :P

Comment: thanks a lot @Axel - your code worked for me...

Answer (score 4):

An answer provided by Axel above  proposed correct solution:
Use {{var customer.id}} and 
{{var customer.rp_token}} to print values in your email