# Create and send email to customer reset password link programmatically in magento

Tags: php, magento, reset

How to create a reset password link in magento and then send the mail to the corresponding customer.I have referred this link:

```
    1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034753/magento-customer-password-reset-email
```

But i don't know what is going inside that code.So kindly answer to solve this.I want to done it manually(programmatically)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
        /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
            ->loadByEmail($yourCustomerEmail);
        if ($customer->getId()) {
            try {
                $newResetPasswordLinkToken =  Mage::helper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
                $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
                $customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
            } catch (Exception $exception) {
                Mage::log($exception);
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you pls tell me what is this function?

Comment: It's pretty much the same code that gets executed on the forgotPasswordPostAction of the AccountController. If you want to understand more you can read the documentation and the source code of Magento: http://doc-magento.com/nav.html?app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php.source.html